# How to build a one page website with top navigation bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigation

I want to build a one-page-website using Google flutter.
Example: https://www.gerardstric.com

The website should have a top navigation bar on the top and if I click on the items, it should jump to the corresponding text on the one-page-website.

Is it possible using flutter? If yes, is there a way without using a package?

Thanks for helping in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question boils down to how you can create a button that causes the page to scroll to a specific Flutter Widget. This is definitely possible in Flutter:

1. Add a `GlobalKey` to the `key` parameter of the widget you'd like to scroll to.
2. Call `Scrollable.ensureVisible();`

Here's a sample app that does just this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final scrollKey = GlobalKey();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 64,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: TextButton(
                  child: const Text("Scroll to Section"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Scrollable.ensureVisible(
                      scrollKey.currentContext ?? context,
                      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 2000,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              Container(
                key: scrollKey,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text("Section You Wanted To Scroll To"),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 2000,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can create as many `GlobalKey`s as you would like to represent the different sections on your page. As requested, this uses no third-party packages.

Comment: FYI the OP has shown no effort of their own, only a general requirement. Not something that can be answered objectively (there's no specific question to answer)